# Mediawiki shows own PHP source code

Tags: php, mediawiki

again, I have a strange fail in the Mediawiki. If a link is formated like this:

www.path-to-my-wiki.net/wiki_path/index.php?title=blah

The Server will prompt out the source code (no joke) of the php file!

(Sample:)

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the main web entry point for MediaWiki.
 *
 ...
 *
 * @file
 */


# Initialise common code
$preIP = dirname( __FILE__ );
require_once( "$preIP/includes/WebStart.php" );

# Initialize MediaWiki base class
require_once( "$preIP/includes/Wiki.php" );
$mediaWiki = new MediaWiki();

wfProfileIn( 'main-misc-setup' );
OutputPage::setEncodings(); # Not really used yet

$maxLag = $wgRequest->getVal( 'maxlag' );
if( !is_null( $maxLag ) && !$mediaWiki->checkMaxLag( $maxLag ) ) {
    exit;
}
```

If the link will be like this:

www.path-to-my-wiki.net/wiki/blah

The Server will not prompt out the PHP source code, but the desired page.

I have not changed anyting regarding the webserver and Mediawiki configuration, and this wiki is not reachable from the internet. But I doubt that I am not the only one, who is working with this Mediawiki.

Comment: i think you need to rewrite  the url ... you can do this in htaccess file

Comment: server misconfiguration - it's not treating php files as php scripts, it's treating them as plain text files, and serving them up as such. with the `/wiki/blah/...` version, there's probably a mod_rewrite+htaccess set in place that DOES treat php files as php scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Apache configuration does not have a handler assigned for the `.php` extension, but does for Rewrites. You will most likely need to supply your .htaccess to get more answers.

Comment: @ registered-user, @ marc-b, @sixeightzero: That was my first thought, too. The .htaccess haven't been changed. Nor the apache configuration for the PHP interpreter. Afer long research the failure was in "another castle". There was an url-pass in the proxy configuration missing. This problem was there since the beginning, but was not recognized because the wiki was not moved out of the proxy-server...